# Pause a function to listen to requests

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running a long loop inside a function in NodeJS and knowing that JS by its nature does not allow anything to interrupt a function, I wanted to know is their a way to pause a function's execution to listen to requests from client that I am no able to do currently

Comment: you can use generators

Comment: the only thing that generators help with is giving back the control to the caller which in any case will be another function. And I don't know if I can get requests made from another function

Comment: Instead of implementing a pause feature, change your design. Try to store all requests in a queue(object variable), run a while loop and just keep listening to the queue.

Comment: but while a function in executing, is there anything you can do before the function is fully executed

Comment: Can you specify your actual problem statement, it will be much easier to answer

Comment: So I am running a long job with too many elements which need to be processed in the order they are there. But at anytime if the job is not required anymore i need to stop it with a post call that I will make, but while the loop is running the requests don't get processed in node js they are just queued

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145016/discussion-between-akabhirav-and-niraj).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot interrupt a function while it is executing. What you need to do is refactoring the loop that causes problems.

You must break the loop itself:

- Instead of a loop, each iteration should call the next using `setTimeout()`
- Use a generator. Passing to and from a generator breaks the eventloop and allows other events executing in between.

This is what I mean by using setTimeout :

Given the function :

```
function syncLoop(args) {
    var localVar;
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        doSomething(args, localVar) 
    } 
}
```

Replace the loop with `setTimeout` (or `setImmediate()`), like this :

```
function asyncLoop(args) {
    var localVar; 
    function innerLoop(i){ if(i < max){ 
         doSomething(args, localVar) 
         setTimeout(function(){
               i++; innerLoop(i); 
         }, 0);
     } } 
    innerLoop(0);
}
```

This way, at each iteration, the control is passed to the event loop, and other independent requests can be served.

Comment: I already tried generator, all it does is give control back to the caller function which still does not allow the other events to occur. If I am getting something wrong, maybe i'll understand properly if you give a code sample. thanks

Comment: @akabhirav maybe I'm late. I gave some code for implementing a loop with setTimeout. As for generators I didn't yet try myself.

Answer (score 0):

There's not very good idea to stop requests handle. Try use promises, this is very rough example but you can understand base idea:

```
...
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    let bigData = [];

    //parse your big data in bigData
    ...

    new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        for(let i = 0; i < bigData.length; i++){
            //some long calculate process

            //if error
             return reject(error);

            //if all calculated
             return resolve(result);
        }
    })
    .then(function(result){
        res.end(result);
    }, function(function(error){
        throw error;
    });
});
...
```

Maybe try this:

```
let count = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < bigData.length; i++){

    /*something calculation
        ....
    */
    count++;

    //this code allow your server every 50 iterations "take a brake" and handle other requests
    if(count === 50){
        count = 0;
        setTimeout(()=>{ 
        }, 100);
    };

};
```

Comment: but what I am talking about is that when the callback in promise will run, it will stop listening to the requests and queue them, this is because js is single threaded and while executing a function it does not do anything else, however i will give it a try and reply if it works shortly

Comment: Nope, didn't work, once the function execution starts there is no way to interrupt it.

Comment: Your timeout does not what it should.It does not break the loop. The loop will run to completion before the setTimeout function gets executed.